# search through SQLite using selection args[] dispay nothing

Tags: android, database, sqlite, search

i've trying to develop an application that have function to search words in database. i use the selection args because when i use query it's keep show errors at the wildcard.
use the selection args don't show any errors but it display nothing in my listview. here's my code.. hope you can help me to fix the problem

public ArrayList search(String b) throws SQLException {

```
    db = getReadableDatabase();
    qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String [] sqlSelect = {KEY_ROWID, KEY_SURA, KEY_INDO}; 

    //String q = "Alif laam miim.";

    qb.setTables(DATABASE_TABLE);
    String[] args = {b};
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, KEY_INDO + " = ?" , args ,null,
            null, null, null);
    String result = "";
    ArrayList<String> string = new ArrayList<String>();
    int index = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_INDO);
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result =c.getString(index);
        string.add(result);
    }
    return string;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of Querybuilder. Use this

```
Cursor c = db.query("TABLE_NAME", null, "Col_Name=?", args, null);
```